# Magento Reindexing Issue in SSH

Tags: magento, ssh

### Reindexing issue in Magento via SSH

I reindexed magento through ssh but it still not working.

I have tried all commands

```
  php -f indexer.php -- reindexall  
  Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]  
  --status <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Status  
  --mode <indexer>                Show Indexer(s) Index Mode  
  --mode-realtime <indexer>       Set index mode type "Update on Save"  
  --mode-manual <indexer>         Set index mode type "Manual Update"  
  --reindex <indexer>             Reindex Data  
  info                            Show allowed indexers  
  reindexall                      Reindex Data by all indexers  
  help                            This help  </b>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly "is still not working" mean? What errors do you get, if any, and what is the expected behavior? Thanks. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: If I entered the command through ssh, it showing the above help lines. I need to reindex my magento data. Reindexing through magento admin, catalog_url_rewrites not working showing "data not received error". Reindexing through ssh showing only help commands.

Answer (score 0):

there might be syntax error getting picked up from your shell try:

`php indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: I have tried out all the commands still showing only the help lines.

Comment: did you try copy and paste from my example? if not, you should

Comment: I have not copy past the command. Still showing same help commands.                 php indexer.php reindexall
Content-type: text/html
Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

Answer (score 0):

Run the below php script in magento root folder if any error means you will get or else script will run without even timeout also

```
 <?php
 require_once('app/Mage.php');         
 umask(0);
 Mage::app();

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 172800);
 ini_set('memory_limit', 1024000000);

 echo "start";
 $indexer = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_url');
 $indexer->reindexEverything();
 echo "end";
```